# Window and Iframe handling in selenium webdriver

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario.

1.One page is loaded after that we are switching to iFrame in that page.

2.From iFrame we are clicking on Login button.

3.Now the application is landed in different page.

How can I get selenium driver control back from iFrame to this page?. Because if I use switch.defaultContent() to get back the control from iFrame it will be going to the page from where the iFrame is called. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to the ActiveElement. This should give you the first focussed element on the new page.